# What's the difference between Lazy.Force() and Lazy.Value

Tags: .net, f#, lazy-evaluation

On the MSDN documentation for `Lazy.Force<T>` extension method says:

> Forces the execution of this value and returns its result. Same as
>   Value. Mutual exclusion is used to prevent other threads from also
>   computing the value.

Does it mean that it's equivalent to creating a `Lazy<T>` instance with `ExecutionAndPublication` [LazyThreadSafetyMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode.aspx) so that only one thread can initialize the instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. They are both the same, and both make sure that the value will be computed only once.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit strange that the method exists and is not a function - it's not composable and replicates the behavior of `.Value`.

I would define something like the following ([as seen in the F# compiler](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/f9ea5824a321a0df73675ad392458af79297f092/src/absil/illib.fs#L605)):

```ml
module Lazy =
    // Lazy.force : Lazy<'T> -> 'T
    let force (x: Lazy<'T>) = x.Force()
```